# how to make Text color change, when mouse move on the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need change the text color , when mouse move on the images,

Here i have done some work. i can't able to change the text color. can anyone please help me.

html:

```
<div class="hover">
<a href=""><img src="th.jpg" /><span>Add</span></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hover
{
width:65px;
height:56px;
display:inline;
text-align:center;
}
.hover a
{
color:#000;
display:block;
margin:0 5px 0 0;
float:left;
text-align:center;
height:56px;
text-decoration:none;
width:65px;
}
.hover span {
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
.hover img {
margin:0 auto;
padding:3px 0;
}
.hover img:hover{
border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Don't overlook the [tag:JavaScript] tag: image and text are siblings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
.hover img:hover{
border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

to

```
.hover a:hover img{
border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Early IEs don't support hover on elements other than "a"

Changing text color:

```
.hover a:hover{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hover:hover`, or `.hover a:hover`, or `img:hover + span`. You may have to explicitly set the child elements to inherit their text color.

The first two won't do exactly what you want, but try them if the last one doesn't work.

If you really want to have it just trigger on hover over the image, but change the style in another element, probably jquery is the way to go if the last of the three selectors above doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
.hover a:hover {
   color: #whatevercoloryouwant;
}
```

Some older browsers will ignore hovering on anything other than a link. Therefore my choice for the 'a'.

XpertEase

Answer (score 0):

if you want the text within the  tag to change color then the CSS should be:

```
.hover a span{ /* THE STYLE FOR THE SPAN */ }
.hover a:hover span{ /* THE STYLE FOR THE SPAN ON MOUSEOVER */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by writing CSS for the outer  tag.
e.g.

a:hover {
    color:green;
}

That will change the color of any text inside the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

using html and css you can do something like this;

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
td.menuon { color: #CC0000; }
td.menuoff { color: #000000; }
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="menuoff" onmouseover="className='menuon';" onmouseout="className='menuoff';">
test
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

save it as a html document and open in browser texts goes red on mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your css:

```
.hover a:hover { color:red; /* or whatever color you want */ }
```